# tex4ht: what to do if a font is missing

Tags: tex4ht

I have just started to learn the features of the `tex4ht` tool. It is working with one exception: Compiling

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{igo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% 
\begin{document}
%% 
\begin{minipage}[c][1.0\height][r]{0.5\textwidth}
\cleargoban\gobansize{19}\igofontsize{8}
\black{e3,e4,b4,a3,a4,d4,g3,g2,c4,d2}
\white{b1,b3,f2,e2,d3,c3,a2}
\copytogoban{1111}
\shortstack{\showgoban[a1,t11]}\par
\texttt{P-001 (C): Black plays}\par
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

with `tex4ht` I get the error message

```
[37m[STATUS]  [0mmake4ht: Conversion started
[37m[STATUS]  [0mmake4ht: Input file: mwe-igo.tex
--- warning --- Couldn't find font `igowhitei8.htf' (char codes: 0--127)
```

Later the compiler tries to generate the font, but failed with e.g.

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode cx --bdpi 300 --mag 1+276/300 --dpi 576 igowhitei8
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for igowhitei8.
mktexpk: perhaps igowhitei8 is missing from the map file.
```

I have everything correctly installed and `pdflatex` is working without any error message. What also pop-up after the warning is the following (longer) message:

```
----------------------------------------------------
environment file
----------------------------------------------------
% unix/tex4ht.env (2019-03-07), generated from tex4ht-env.tex, and
% modified by hand for TeX Live (unix).
% Copyright 2009-2019 TeX Users Group
% Copyright 1997-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
..
%
tpath/tex/texmf/fonts/tfm/!
```

I have no `/tex/texmf/fonts/tfm` directory everything is installed in the usual `~/Library/texmf` on my iMac. Looking around I found a discussion [1](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2018q2/001974.html), which indicates that I have to change somewhere the directory remark. But how, if my guess is correct?

Finale remark: the `igo` is not part of TL, but can be found on CTAN [2](https://ctan.org/pkg/igo). The Type1-Files one can get from [3](https://github.com/otrego/go-type1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX4ht needs font mapping tables for all fonts that it encounters. They map characters from the font to Unicode characters. When such mapping is missing, it will show the error message you see.

For text fonts, we have helper tool for the creation of these mapping files, [htfgen](https://github.com/michal-h21/htfgen). But for more complicated fonts, like math or various picture based fonts, that don't have corresponding Unicode characters, the situation is more difficult, and the mapping needs to be done by hand.

In your example, the font provided by the `igo` package seems to be used only in pictures of the game board. This game board must be converted to a picture to keep its appearance. This conversion to picture is done by a DVI to picture converters, such as Dvipng or Dvisvgm. In that case, you don't need the mapping, you can just use a dummy `.htf` file that suppresses the error message.

You can create dummy `.htf` files with the following command:

```
for i in *.tfm; do echo ".lm-ec" > ${i%.*}.htf; done
```

If you want them to be available on your system, place these files to your [local TEXMF tree](https://www.ugr.es/%7Eftorralbo/blog/programming/local-texmf/), for example this path works on my system:

```
 ~/texmf/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/igo/
```

I guess, that this path:

```
 ~/Library/texmf/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/igo/
```

should work for you.

And to create a picture for the game board, use the following file, `igo.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{showgoban}{2}
\def\:tempa#1#2#3#4{\a:showgoban\o:igo@showgoban:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\b:showgoban}
\HLet\igo@showgoban\:tempa

\Configure{showgoban}{\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}

\Hinput{igo}
```

You can place this file to

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/generic/tex4ht/igo.4ht
```

It redefines the command used to print the board and calls the `\Picture` and `\EndPicture` commands to request conversion of the contained code to a picture. See [TeX4ht documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/ForDevelopers.html#tutorial-basic-support-for-a-new-package) for more information about `.4ht` files. Place this file in the same directory as your document.

Compile your file using:

```
 make4ht -m draft mwe-igo.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: @michael.h21 OK, I will work on it.

Comment: Still a question: Where do I have to store the generated htf-files? And the calling steps are the following: name of the file `igo.tex`, `latex igo`,`tex4ht igo.dvi`?

Comment: The following message pops up:

`(igoblacki8.htf)`
`Searching `lm-ec.htf' for `igoblacki8.htf'`
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/lm/lm-ec.htf)
`--- warning --- File `lm-ec.htf' starts/ends with character code 255 (instead of 127)`
`--- warning --- File `lm-ec.htf' starts/ends with character code 255 (instead of 127)}`

Comment: @Ulrich I've updated my answer with more details. You can ignore the warning about start/end character, it just means that the mapping file expects a different number of characters than what the font uses.

Comment: @michael.h21 Yes, everything is working. Great tool, great support.

Comment: @michael.h21 I just installed the `htfgen` package to understand a little bit more the  technique. It is working, but the `tex` command should be `etex` I guess. Now my question: If I add `\Large\blackstone[6]`to my `tex`-file, then nothing happens (as expected), just a , or something like that. You wrote, that in this case one has to make the mapping by hand. But how? Is there somewhere in your documentation a guideline?

Comment: @Ulrich for hand created font files, see this bit of documentation: https://tug.org/tex4ht/doc/mn-htf.html I guess that in your case, you will want to convert characters to pictures, so you can use "1" as the second field in the character line

Comment: @michael.h21 I try to understand what is written there. I have `myigo10.mf` as my basic font and started with the explanation in the link. Unclear for me is how to fill the lines between `myigo10 0 255` `...``myigo10 0 255`? What is `string class comment` in my case and what are the pictures you are mentioning? Sorry, for asking this but it is the first time I am such deep in the system.

Comment: @Ulrich on each line, you need to provide a mapping for a character from your font. so, if you have font that have all characters, it will start at 0, and you will have 255 lines, where string would be character or html entity, class usually empty string, and comment is optional, but usually it contains the character name. if your font doesn't produce characters that are part of Unicode, then string can be empty, and class can be "1". TeX4ht will then this character convert to picture, so you will get a correct representation in your HTML.

Comment: @michael.h21 Could you please help me (see the "answer" below) hopefully the last time?

Comment: @Ulrich yes, but I am but busy at the moment. hopefully later today.

Comment: @michael.h21 Thank you and sorry for disturbing your day.

Comment: @Ulrich that's OK. I was able to look at your update only now. Could you please post it as a new question? I also don't know how you generated the `igobl10.mf` and `igowh10.mf` files, could you give some instructions?

Comment: @michael.h21: I opened a new question under <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657011/tex4h-and-igo-font> .

Answer (score 0):

What I have done based on the last suggestion:

1. Creating `igobl10.mf` and `igowh10.mf` using the original `mf`-files from the `igo` package and generated the `tfm` etc. files.
2. Creating `mwe-mf.tex` :

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \font\mybl=igobl10
    \font\mywh=igowh10
    \begin{document}
    {\mybl \char0 \char10}   
    {\mywh \char1 \char10}
    \end{document}
```

which is working properly.

3. Next step was the testing:

```
    \documentclass{article}  
    \input showfonts.4ht  
    \begin{document}  
    \showfonts  
    {igobl10}  
    {igowh10}
    {}
    \end{document}
```

The PDF-File showed the right glyphs. There has been error messages, that some characters are missing, e.g. `Missing character: There is no ¡ in font igobl10!`. But this is as expected.  [Here part of the PDF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuLs2.jpg)

4. Then I run `make4ht -m draft mwe-mf.tex` and I got the error message (e.g.)

```
    --- warning --- Couldn't find font igowh10.htf (char codes: 0--127)`
```

5. I generated the `htf` files `igobl10.htf` and `igowh10.htf` entering

```
    igobl10 0 127    <-- line 1
    ’’  ’1’          <-- line 2
    ’’  ’1’ 
    ’’  ’1’  
    ... 
    ’’  ’1’         <-- line 129
    igobl10 0 127   <-- line 130
```

where line 2 until line 129 (= 127 - 0 + 1) contains the `'' '1'` and stored them in the same directory as the `TeX`-file

6. Now running `make4ht`I get the error message

```
    --- warning --- Improper signature at start of file `.htf'
    --- warning --- File `igowh10.htf' starts/ends with character code 0 (instead of 127)
    igowh10 0 127
    0:  ’’    ’1’ 
    1:  ’’    ’1’ 
    2:  ’’    ’1’ 
    ...
    127:  ’’    ’1’ 
     128:  igowh10  0 127--- error --- Improper file `igowh10.htf'
```

If I commenting out the line `{\mywh \char1 \char10}` in my TeX-file I get

```
    [STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: mwe-mf.tex
    --- warning --- Improper entry (line 0)
    --- warning --- Improper entry (line 1)
    ....
    --- warning --- Improper entry (line 125)
    --- warning --- Improper entry (line 126)
    igobl10 0 127
    0:   ’’  ’1’ 
    1:   ’’  ’1’ 
    2:   ’’  ’1’ 
    ...
    126:   ’’  ’1’ 
    127:   ’’  ’1’  
    128:  igobl10 0 127--- error --- Improper file `igobl10.htf'
```

Can you give me a hint what I am doing wrong?